# SqlSyncProvider custom transformation

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

Does anyone know if it is possible to customize sync using SqlSyncProvider such that I can sync non identical databases (both sql servers) using custom transformations.

For e.g. say I have database1 containing a Person table with cols 'FirstName' and 'LastName', and I have database2 with Person table with a single column 'Name' and I want the sync to  transform database2.Person.Name = database1.Person.FirstName + database1.Person.LastName.

Regards,

Ilias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that should be possible. you can provision the tables as it is, but intercept the changes and manipulate them.

check out a similar approach here:

[Synching with different column keys](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/upload-synchronization-where-the-client-and-server-primary-keys-are-different/)

[Part 4 – Synchronizing Tables With Different Table Names and Column Names](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/part-4-synchronizing-tables-with-different-table-names-and-column-names/)

the process should be almost the same.